# Changing value on bullet leaving screen

Tags: java, processing

I have this bunch of badly written code in Processing 3.5.3.
I want the "drone" to shoot again when the "bullet" leaves the screen, but it starts glitching.
Any ideas, what can be wrong, or how to improve the screen leaving detections or things like that.
I copied here the whole code so you can try it out because it isn't so complicated yet

```java
int charx;
int chary;
void setup() {
  charx = width/2;
  chary = height - height/10;
  fullScreen();
  background(0);
}
void keyPressed(){
  if(key=='w'){if(!(chary<30))chary-=15;}}
  if(key=='s'){if(!(chary>height-60)){chary+=15;}}
  if(key=='a'){charx-=15;if(charx<30){charx=width-30;}}
  if(key=='d'){charx+=15;if(charx>width-30){charx=30;}}
}
int bullet(int x, int y) {
  if ( y > height - 30){return(0);}
  fill(175, 0, 0);
  triangle(x, y, x-8, y-16, x+8, y-16);
  fill(255);
  return(1);
}
int launch = 0;
int starterx = 0;
int drone1(float startx, float xm, int y, int i) {
  int x = ceil(startx) + ceil(40 * sin(xm));
  if (i == 0) {
    starterx = ceil(startx);
  } else {
    if (launch == 0) {
      starterx = x;
      launch = 1;
      return(0);
    }}
  fill(0, 200, 50);
  rect(x, y, 30, 30);
  fill(255);
  if (launch == 1) {
    launch = bullet(ceil(asin(x)) + starterx + 15, y + 46 + i * 3);
  }
  return(1);}
void player(int x, int y) {
  fill(255);
  rect(x, y, 10, 10);
  fill(51, 51, 204);
  rect(x+10, y, 10, 10);
  rect(x-10, y, 10, 10);
  fill(255, 215, 0);
  rect(x, y-10, 10, 10);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  rect(x+10, y+10, 10, 10);
  rect(x-10, y+10, 10, 10);
  fill(255);
}
int i = 0; 
int bulletmover = 0;
void draw() {
  background(0);
  player(charx, chary);
  int bultr = 1;
  if (bultr == 1) {
    bultr = drone1(width/2, 0.1 * i, i, bulletmover);
  } else {
    bulletmover = 0;
    bultr = 1;
  }
  bulletmover += 1;
  i += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some dead code (code that is never run) in your `draw` loop. When you write

```java
if (bultr == 1) {
  bultr = drone1(width/2, 0.1 * i, i, bulletmover);
} else {
  bulletmover = 0;
  bultr = 1;
}
```

the computer does this:

1. Do one of the following. If `bultr` is 1, do (a), otherwise do (b).

   - (a) Execute `drone1(...)`, and set `bultr` to that output.
   - (b) Set `bulletmover` to 0 and `bultr` to 1.
2. Proceed to the code after the `if...else` statement.

So if you put `int bultr = 1` directly before that, the computer will *always* see that `bultr` is 1, so it will always do (a) and never (b). I didn't read your code all that thoroughly, but I think what you were trying to do is this:

1. If `bultr` is 1, execute `drone1(...)`, and set `bultr` to that output.
2. If `bultr` is not 1, set `bulletmover` to 0 and `bultr` to 1.
3. Proceed to the code after the `if...else` statement.

In code, that would look like this:

```java
if (bultr == 1) {
  bultr = drone1(width/2, 0.1 * i, i, bulletmover);
}
if (bultr != 1) {
  bulletmover = 0;
  bultr = 1;
}
```